# how to pass start and end date from html page to views.py (django)

Tags: django

i am using daterangepicker in my django project  ,
need to know how to pass the start date  and end date to views.py (DJANGO) for processing further and get report.

```js
              <script>
                var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
                var end = moment();

                $(function () {
                  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    opens: 'left',
                    showDropdowns: true,
                    "drops": "auto",
                    startDate: start,
                    endDate: end,
                    ranges: {
                      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    }
                  }, function (start, end, label) {
                    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                  });

                });
              </script>
```

```html
<div>

                <input type="text" name="daterange" />
                {% csrf_token %}
              </div>
```

Comment: you have get it in your views.py like this `start_date = request.POST.get('daterange')`

Comment: thanks Ankit, but after adding start_date = request.POST.get('daterange')  i am not able to get data rage in python . can you point me any sample or link where i can learn how to get

Comment: provide your form action and your `views.py` how you are trying to get let me check

Comment: i am in learning process to implement . in my HTML template i have this

Comment: pls find the function i am using in views.py (Note: i am in process of learning) . not sure i need to add any form 
def reportgeneration(request):
    start_date = request.POST.get('daterange')
    print(start_date)

Comment: and what is the action of your form

Comment: Hello @ Balakumar Rajendran did it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your problem you have to get your input value inside `request.method`
like this

```
def reportgeneration(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    start_date = request.POST.get('daterange')
    print(start_date)
```

**Update**

You have to add all fields inside `form` tag eg. `<form>..here all inputs..</form>`

```
<div>
  <form action="{% url 'reportgeneration' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" name="daterange" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: should is need to add any post method in my html also ?

Comment: in your form like this `<form action="your_url" method="POST">`

Comment: Hello @BalakumarRajendran did my answer solved your problem

Comment: i updated my html <div>
                <form action="/reportgeneration" method="POST"></form>
                <input type="text" name="daterange" />
                {% csrf_token %}
              </div>
and my views.py funcito is def reportgeneration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        start_date = request.POST.get('daterange')
        print(start_date)

Comment: i am still not able to pass the date to my views.py.

Comment: you have to add this code in your question for better view

Comment: you have to add `input` inside `form` tag

Comment: Hello @BalakumarRajendran check i have edited my answer and provided improved your `HTML` code

Answer (score 0):

my HTML code is

```html
 <!-- date range picker start -->
              <div>
                <form action="/reportgeneration" method="POST"></form>
                <input type="text" name="daterange" />
                {% csrf_token %}
              </div>


              <script>
                var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
                var end = moment();

                $(function () {
                  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    opens: 'left',
                    showDropdowns: true,
                    "drops": "auto",
                    startDate: start,
                    endDate: end,
                    ranges: {
                      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                    }
                  }, function (start, end, label) {
                    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                  });

                });
              </script>
              <!-- date range picker end -->
```

Comment: Hello @Balakumar Rajendran you don't have to put your question as an answer you have to just edit your question

Comment: and check i edited my answer copy the `HTML` code and try

Comment: no luck . updated html and  i am not able get the date in python

Comment: how you are submitting your form

Comment: you have to add this `<input type="submit" value="submit">`